# Using CJK character orientation in label expression of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript, internationalization, chinese

I'd like to set label expressions by VBscript in ArcGIS, here comes the problem.
Since labels are constructed by Chinese and English, so I set the label expression like:

[image]

If CJK character is checked, Chinese labels would ideally arranged whereas English labels would not.

(1) CJK character is not checked:

[image]

(2) CJK character is checked:

[image]

I want the labels to be arranged like Chinese in (2) and English in (1).

Comment: I am wondering whether your question is related to http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/vertical-placement-for-asian-text.htm  Can you please show what your current labels look like and show or describe what you want them to look like, please?

Comment: The website shows how to set labels symply in  Asian text, whereas the labels are composed of Chinese and English in my case. I have uploaded what's the labels look like, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CJK option](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/vertical-placement-for-asian-text.htm) is only available for certain fonts, where glyphs are stored both with a baseline underneath and also to the left hand side.

When Maplex is placing text, one of these two glyphs will be chosen, depending on whether the CJK option is checked and on the angle of the feature.

Latin characters are only available with the baseline underneath, so will not rotate at the same time as CJK characters. In example (2) above, the Chinese characters are using the vertical form (left-hand baseline), but the English characters are still using the horizontal form, as it is the only one available.

It may be possible to achieve the effect you are after by having two label classes - one for English and one for Chinese - but then the labels for one feature may not be placed near each other.